# Courses or sources to learn ANOVA

Tags: self-study, anova, software

What sources would you recommend to learn ANOVA (with and without software)?

What are the prerequisites?

If you could recommend me a complete course, online or books  (I'd prefer videos but books/notes are fine too) such that start from the very *beginning* (like you have the idea of what ANOVA is) and then eventually increases the level up to the point to have very *advanced* and difficult knowledge (like research knowledge), that'd be great :)

Thank you for any help that you can provide.

Comment: you don't need to take a course on ANOVA, in fact, ANOVA is only covered during 1-2 days in a full semester course in graduate-level biostatistics.  ANOVA basically determines if 3 or more averages (from 3 or more samples) are significantly different from one another.  If only two samples are involved, then a t-test is used, not ANOVA.

Comment: @NXGLogic Did you learn ANOVA in 1-2 days? how did you do that? Did you learn with and without software too? \\ btw I am not in a graduate level yet

Comment: I wouldn't recommend focusing singly on a statistical method (e.g., ANOVA), for a learning requirement and then think you don't need to learn something else.  There are always assumptions that have to be met when applying any method, and they can be based on many other things besides the method alone.

Comment: @NXGLogic Okay :) shouldn't be one step at a time?  First ANOVA, then something else? Anyway I've watched the [3 videos](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/statistics-probability/analysis-of-variance-anova-library) by KhanAcademy, afaik there's no more videos about this topic on Khan.. meh

Comment: The free version of our Explorer package has a detailed user guide with a fully-worked out example for ANOVA with all equations and answers (exact copy of what you would get in a stat lecture), and then an example run.

Comment: @NXGLogic ohh ok. Sounds interesting, I'll check it ^^ thank you.